On Teltonika Router the gateways of seperate networks are pingable. Security Issue?
I have an Issue with a RUTX08 though I’m certain the same issue would occur with similar devices.
I have setup three different networks each with their own VLAN and IP-range. For some reason I’m still able to get an ICMP echo reply from all of the gateways, no matter from where I ping. ARP-requests are not answered though.
There are no NAT-rules or port forwards set up. Also no network bridges and the likes. The output and forward rules of the networks are all set to either drop or reject but the router doesn’t seem to care. In my humble opinion it shouldn’t happen either way because the VLANs would already separate the networks. Also the Firewall and different IP-ranges should make it impossible to receive an answer.
I think that maybe the networking chip being one device that hosts the three virtual interfaces and three gateways is the problem. Even though the questions arise...
Is there a way to prevent that? How can this be explained and does it have consequences for network security since the separation of the networks seems to be rather questionable?
Thanks in advance

They are not gateways – they're gateway addresses and the RUTX08 itself is the 'gateway' that holds all those addresses. You're not creating "virtual gateways" as actually separate entities, you're only assigning more addresses to the same system.
The RUTX08 runs a Linux variant (RūtOS is an OpenWrt derivative), and Linux considers that all IPv4 addresses on all interfaces of the same host actually belong to the host as a whole, not to each specific interface. Packets addressed to any of the host's IP addresses are therefore mapped to the input iptables chain – not to the forward chain – because in truth they're not being forwarded anywhere outside of the 'host'.
This behavior varies between operating systems; some OS have stronger separation between interfaces, others not. (I think the technical term is "weak-host model" vs "strong-host model".) But it usually does not matter because the packets don't exit the host either way – although you can talk to the gateway, you still cannot talk through it, as your firewall rules will still prevent that.
Related note: The output chain is not "output to the network", it is specifically "output from this host to the network" (i.e. packets generated by the RUTX08 itself instead of forwarded). Most likely it does not prevent the router from generating ICMP ping replies because the config frontend has a hidden rule to allow all 'established' packets.

different IP-ranges should make it impossible to receive an answer

They don't, because the router has a route to the sender's network, so it can send the packets there (without requiring NAT). Different IP ranges have never been a problem in itself; indeed the entire Internet works this way.

In my humble opinion it shouldn’t happen either way because the VLANs would already separate the networks

Well, yes, but the entire purpose of a router is in fact to forward traffic between such separated networks.
VLANs only deal with Ethernet layer separation, e.g. things like ARP queries and other MAC-addressed traffic. That is, they prevent host A from addressing its packets directly to the MAC address of host B. But that's not what is happening here – the packets are being sent to a router's MAC address, which is a valid MAC address in the current VLAN, so they properly reach the router. Once they get there, IP-layer rules apply.

I think that maybe the networking chip being one device that hosts the three virtual interfaces and three gateways is the problem. Even though the questions arise...

The only such networking chip is the router's CPU which runs its main OS. (The RUTX08 doesn't have dedicated circuitry for IP – it has an Ethernet switching chip that handles MAC-level forwarding and VLAN tagging, but packets that are addressed to the router's MAC get forwarded to its CPU for software handling.)

How can this be explained and does it have consequences for network security since the separation of the networks seems to be rather questionable?

The short explanation is that the packets do not actually enter the other network. You can think of it like this: Although IP addresses appear as if they're configured on interfaces (and interfaces belong to networks), they really exist at the center point (the host itself) that is merely connected to all those networks but doesn't quite belong to any them – in the Linux model at least.
